# How to display ENUM as string in ListView in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I am trying to display `StandardEventLevel` as text, but I don't understand how to do so.

My XAML-code (Level is `StandardEventLevel` Enumeration):

```
<ListView x:Name="eventsView" 
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          MouseDoubleClick="eventsView_MouseDoubleClick" >

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" 
                            Header="Level" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This works out of the box when `Level` is a public property of the class that you use for the items in the ListView.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found my mistake - I had to use LevelDisplayName, not Level property!

Comment: Reworded the title to be more understandable, as well as the body and syntax